# Using the Continuting Correction in this example

Tags: probability

I'm studying the continuity correction and working on this example and kind got confused at some point so I'll appreciate any clarification.

*A new computer virus attacks a folder consisting of  **200**  files. Each file gets damaged with probability of **0.2 independently** of other files. What is the probability that **fewer than 50 files** get damaged?*

So from that question this is how I worked it out. Since I'm given the probability of damage and the number of files so I'm taking this a a binomial distribution, so first I'm going to check if the Normal approximation is going to work by the following:

[1] np = 200 * 0.2 = 40 (**np>10**)

[2] n(1-p) = 200 (1-0.2) = 160 (**n(1-p)>10**)

From the above it shows that I can use the Normal approximation to Binomial.
This is where I get confused, I would like to make sure the following is correct because  at some point I got confused as to subtract of add **0.5**.

P(x<50) = P(x< 50+0.5) = P(x<50.5) = answer

So the question is am I going to add as per the continuity rule that goes as follows :

**P(a-0.5 < X < b+0.5)**

Any clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a [link](http://www.statisticshowto.com/what-is-the-continuity-correction-factor/)  that was provided as an answer to a similar question to mine and it clarified my confusion!

The table goes as follows:

If **P(X=n)** use   P(n – 0.5 < X < n + 0.5)

If  **P(X>n)** use   P(X > n + 0.5)

If  **P(X≤n)**  use    P(X < n + 0.5)

If    **P(X < n)** use  P(X < n – 0.5)

If    **P(X ≥ n)** use   P(X > n – 0.5)

I think that makes a lot of sense and it explains everything.